# DAC hats compatibility RPi2B

Tags: pi-2

new to RPi and using a 2B that was a gift to my son years ago but never used. I would like to buy a digital out DAC HAT but all those I see show compatibility with 3, 4 and Zero but don't seem to list 2B.
Knowing they are "Form Factor" identical does that mean I don't need to worry and they will all work with 2B or are there hidden traps - especially for a new user.

Answer (score 0):

All Pi with a 40 pin header have identical connections.

If the HAT works with a Zero, there should be no issues with a Pi2.

There is no such thing as a 2+.

You probably will need a new OS. The "default" is Bullseye, but this still has implementation issues so I suggest you install Buster - most tutorials are written for Buster. See https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/new-old-functionality-with-raspberry-pi-os-legacy/

Comment: Thank you. 2B not +. My mistake ask a senile newbie.